# Attaching $n$-th root of $p$ to an ring $R = \mathbb{Z}/(p^{k}\mathbb{Z})$, assuming it is not in $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}/(p^{k}\mathbb{Z})$, be a ring and $p$ be any prime number, and $k > 3$ be any integer. Now let $\mu = p^{1/n}$ be the real $n-$th root of $p$. How to define a ring which is attaching $\mu$ with the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}/(p^{k}\mathbb{Z})$. I read from Artin's algebra that it is denoted as $R[\mu]$ where $R[\mu] = \{f(\mu): f \in R[x]\}$. In one place book says that $R[\mu]$ denotes the ring $R[x]/\langle x^{n} - p\rangle$.
My question is these two notations are same? If isomorphic then how can I prove this isomorphism?

If I consider one homomorphism $\phi :\mathbb{Z}/(p^{k}\mathbb{Z})[x] \to \mathbb{Z}/(p^{k}\mathbb{Z})[\mu]$, by $\phi(x)=\mu ~~\&~~ \phi(r)=r ~~ \forall a \in \mathbb{Z}/(p^{k}\mathbb{Z})$. Can we show that $\operatorname{Ker}(\phi)=\langle x^{n} - p\rangle$?

I want to understand how to attach an element in a ring that is not a PID or a field(**For example $\mathbb{Z}/(p^{k}\mathbb{Z})$**) because we can't claim that, the kernel is an ideal so the principal ideal and generated by the smallest power polynomial.